# Can I use pre-"profiles" OpenGL versions on Macs?

Tags: macos, opengl, deprecated

I want to use a deprecated GL function - `glPushAttrib`. Ideally, I'd do that by using the Compatibility profile of a recent GL version, but [Macs don't support that](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractopenglfunctions.html#details). So I'm happy to settle for using an old GL version, from before GL profiles existed. My question, though, is: does Mac support that?

**Note:** Don't tell me that I shouldn't use glPushAttrib unless you're able to link to a good library that replaces it. I don't want to write my own, and using a full-blown engine would be much more trouble than it's worth for my usecase ;)

Comment: Hardly anything that could be saved in a sensible way meaningfully using `glPushAttrib` made it into the modern core profiles anyway. The real question is, why do you insist on using this cumbersome thing called the fixed function pipeline at all?

Comment: @datenwolf: I don't use the fixed function pipeline ;) . I need `glPushAttrib` for `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT`, `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT`, `GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT` and `GL_VIEWPORT_BIT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer [in the OpenGL wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts):

> MacOSX gives you a choice: core profile for versions 3.2 or higher, or just version 2.1